# Get rows where value change from 0 to 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table:

```
id date default(bool)
1 2015-01-01 0
2 2015-01-02 0
3 2015-01-03 1
4 2015-01-04 1
5 2015-01-05 1
6 2015-01-06 0
7 2015-01-07 0
8 2015-01-08 1
9 2015-01-09 1
10 2015-01-10 0
```

I want only rows where ordered by date rows change default column from 0 to 1, so in this table rows: 3 and 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If id can be used instead of date, use a correlated sub-query to read previous row's value:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where default = 1
  and (select default from tablename t2
       where t2.id = t1.id - 1) = 0
```

Use date instead to find previous row:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where default = 1
  and (select default from tablename t2
       where t2.date = (select max(date) from tablename
                        where date < t1.date)) = 0
```

Comment: sorry ids aren't always +1 :(

Comment: + date also isn't +1 day for every row

Comment: Updated, date version added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using dynamic variable

```
select t.id,t.date,t.`default` 
    from ( 
       select 
       t1.*, 
       @default := if(@prev_default = 0 and t1.`default` = 1,1,0) as def,
       @prev_default:=t1.`default` 
       from (
         select * from test order by date
       )t1,
       (select @prev_default:= 2,@default:=0)r
    )t 
    where t.def = 1 ;
```